# Menu floating left and right

Tags: html, css

I have the follow HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item-113"><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        <li class="item-114"><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="item-115"><a href="/bastidores">Bastidores</a></li>
        <li class="item-116"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="item-117"><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#menu{width:900px;margin:0 auto;}
#menu ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu li{float:left;margin:10px;}
#menu .item-115, #menu .item-116, #menu .item-117{float:right;}
```

I want 3 menus floating left and 3 floating right, but they are reverting order.

How to do this?

Comment: Copied your stuff to jsfiddle; it looks correct! http://jsfiddle.net/xeQBd/ Did you applied any list-styles or display to #menu, ul or li?

Comment: The order is `Home Sobre Portfolio Bastidores Blog Contato`. See your jsfiddle: `Home Sobre Portfolio Contato Blog Bastidores`

Comment: You're right on that one, sorry. Posted a answer, that should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/w64Nb/2/

The HTML is identical to what's in your question.

> No, .item-{uid-for-menu} are random, but for each li I can float with jquery last tree menu. – Gabriel Santos
>
> @thirtydot assume the class always will be the same, and suggest one
>   solution, then, I adapt my javascript to generate the same class as my
>   sample class. – Gabriel Santos

Instead of relying on certain classes being present, or forcing them to be the same using JavaScript, you can just solve the whole problem with jQuery (which in a different comment, you said you have available):

```
$($('#menu li').slice(-3).get().reverse())
    .addClass('right').remove().appendTo('#menu .menu');​
```

That will take the last three `li` inside `#menu`, add the `.right` class (which is just `float: right`), and reverse the order in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this. http://jsfiddle.net/xeQBd/1/ 
Simply don't let the 'left' items float; only apply to the ones that you need to float to the right.

```
#menu{width:900px;margin:0 auto;}
#menu ul{
    margin:0;padding:0; display:block;
}
#menu li{
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#menu .item-115, #menu .item-116, #menu .item-117{
    float:right;
}​
```

I've used something like this on www.hoeve-bouwlust.nl/activiteiten in the menu

Comment: The problem is that the order is flipped.

Comment: But you reversed order of menu inside HTML. `<li>Contact en Route</li>`, `<li>Foto's</li>`, `<li>Nieuws</li>`

Comment: You're right, my fault completely. Not a real nice solution, but one that's used from time by time: wrap the elements within another (can be a div, can be a li). http://jsfiddle.net/xeQBd/3/ This question and it's answer reflect you're problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585794/css-reverse-floating-of-elements-how-keep-them-at-the-bottom You just can't do it without changing the html (you can use JS if you like)

Answer (score 2):

Hold each in its own list

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu menu-to-the-left">
        <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item-113"><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        <li class="item-114"><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu menu-to-the-right">
        <li class="item-115"><a href="/bastidores">Bastidores</a></li>
        <li class="item-116"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="item-117"><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

In case you cannot edit the source code, you can do something like this. It involves setting fixed widths on menu items though. **[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2668857)**:

```
#menu {
    width:  900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu ul {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li, #menu li a {
    float:  left;
    width: 100px;
}
#menu li:nth-child(4) {
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but, because the code is auto generated, I cant divide the menu.

Comment: @GabrielSantos: In which case, I doubt this is possible. Interested in others' solutions though.

Comment: I think the same, but I decided to ask, even already having a solution that solves the problem, which is reverse order of tree last li order.

Comment: @GabrielSantos: Will there always be only 6 menu items? Are they of equal widths (or do you care if they would?)

Comment: 6 menu itens, with the width of text inside each one.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with pure css, just set the `display` property of the `li`s to `inline-block` and the `text-align` property of the `ul` to `right`, then `float` the first three `li`s to `left` so they get back to their original position without messing up with the order they are declared in the document. Like this:

```css
#menu{width:900px;margin:0 auto;}
#menu ul{margin:0;padding:0; text-align: right}
#menu li{display:inline-block;margin:10px;}
#menu .item-101, #menu .item-113, #menu .item-114{float: left}​
```

**[Live example:](http://jsfiddle.net/YZcdm/)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#menu{width:900px;margin:0 auto;}
#menu ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
#menu li{margin:10px;width:100px}
.item-115,.item-116,.item-117{float:right;}
.item-101,.item-113,.item-114{float:left;}
```

Comment: Don`t work, and `#menu li{float:left}` and `.item-115,.item-116,.item-117{float:right;}` do the same.

Answer (score 1):

my solution preview:

[image]

i think you can change the order of you menu items, so you only must to reverse order of last three items ([online demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2668736)):

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="item-101"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="item-113"><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        <li class="item-114"><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>

        <!-- reverse order of last three items -->
        <li class="item-117"><a href="/contato">Contato</a></li>
        <li class="item-116"><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="item-115"><a href="/bastidores">Bastidores</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I will do this if can't see other solution. The problem is, the order is generated from backend, which user can edit, and he don't know or want to know he have to reverse order menu..

Comment: @GabrielSantos: When you say the "user can edit", are those classes on the `li`s always going to stay the same? Is it always going to be `.item-101`, `.item-113`, and so on?

Comment: No, `.item-{uid-for-menu}` are random, but for each `li` I can float with jquery last tree menu.

Comment: @thirtydot i think we can use `nth-child(3) ~ li` selector to detect second half of menu items, because only 6 items exists in menu

Comment: @GabrielSantos: Well, the classes not remaining the same means that they can't be used in the solution. Your original question implies that the classes *can* be used. This isn't particularly easy to fix with CSS, and since you're already using JavaScript/jQuery on the page, you might as well just fix this problem with jQuery.

Comment: @thirtydot assume the class always will be the same, and suggest one solution, then, I adapt my javascript to generate the same class as my sample class.

Comment: @GabrielSantos: If you're using JavaScript in connection with *any* part of this (such as to change classes), you should just solve the whole problem with JavaScript to begin with. I'll post an answer..

Comment: @GabrielSantos i thought solution was needed to be pure css, but i was wrong, so thirtydot's solution is good for you. i upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wondering why the order of right-floated element if *flipped*, this how the floats are supposed to behave. It is [all described here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge
>   touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float.

For the three right floated elements in your example, the first one (source-order-wise) aligns with the right edge. The next item in also shifts towards right; only to find *another float* in its way and stops. Likewise for the third float.

The solution is to create *one* right floated container which contains the three supposed-to-be-right-floated elements, floated left.